# Magium\ActiveDirectory Trying to list groups assigned to user

Tags: php, azure, codeigniter

I am trying to use https://github.com/magium/active-directory to list the groups that a user has been assigned. I have passed and granted the Group.Read.All permission

```
 function test()
{
    session_start();

    $config = [
        'authentication' => [
            'ad' => [
                'client_id' =>,
                'client_secret' =>,
                'return_url'    =>,
                'enabled' =>,
                'directory' =>
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();

    $ad = new \Magium\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory(
        new \Magium\Configuration\Config\Repository\ArrayConfigurationRepository($config),
        Zend\Psr7Bridge\Psr7ServerRequest::fromZend(new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request()),
        null, null, "profile openid email offline_access User.Read Group.Read.All ");

    try {
        $entity = $ad->authenticate();
        echo $entity->getName() . '<Br />';
        echo $entity->getOid() . '<Br />';
        echo $entity->getPreferredUsername() . '<Br />';
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($entity);
        echo "</pre>";
    } 
    catch(Magium\ActiveDirectory\InvalidRequestException $e)
    {


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($e);
        echo "</pre>";        
}

}
```

I'm kinda wondering if its possible using the above repo to fetch the user's groups without doing a manual graph call

Any further guidance on this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: With the above code, no error. I'm kinda wondering if its possible using the above repo to fetch the user's groups without doing a manual graph call

Comment: Okay, please edit that information into your question

Answer (score 1):

```
            $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $result = $request->request("GET","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf",[
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $entity->getAccessToken(),
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true'
                ]
            ]
        );
        echo "<pre>";

        print_r(json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents()));
        echo "</pre>";
```

Just easier to do a manual call to /me/memerOf

List of graph api -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Suggested route taken from issues - https://github.com/magium/active-directory/issues/26